# What ceiling/wall lamps fit these ports

Tags: installation, lamp

[image: ceiling port]
[image: wall port]

I am looking for ceiling lamps for the first one and wall lamps for the second port. Since I have a low ceiling in my apartment in an old house, I want to the use of pendant lamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What country is this from? I'm guessing Netherlands as Attema is located there.

Looks like it's a simple two wire terminal block and hanger hook. Under magnification, I can see the screw threads protruding into the opening where the wires insert.

You strip the lamp cord back about 1/4". After turning off the power, loosen the screws, slide the conductors in each terminal opening and tighten.

The lamp hangs from a chain attached to the hook. Allow for slack in the cord so it doesn't pull against the terminal block.

Comment: Yes I live in the Netherlands. I have installed a really basic light bulb for the first one already. Any thought about the second port? The hook can be completely removed from the port.

Comment: Could you please provide me some examples of these sorts of light from IKEA shop?

Comment: On the bottom one, the two smaller diagonal holes are probably made for self-tapping screws. If you measure the distance between, you'll probably find it is a standard dimension used on wall mounted lamps and the base will probably be larger than the plastic box cover. In the US, you'd be dealing with a recessed box, grounding and wire nuts, here you have a nice terminal block that the lamp wires just plug into with screws to finish the contact. The type of base that you need to measure the screw holes for would be like this --> http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/20238746/